# Is it possible to call powershell cmdlets asynchronously?

Tags: powershell, asynchronous

Say i have cmdlet1 and cmdlet2, both are long running tasks.  Normally i would have a batch file which calls the two cmdlets in order:

```
call powershell cmdlet1
call powershell cmdlet2
```

Is there anyway to set them off asynchronously?

Answer (score 9):

If you're on PowerShell 2, you can use background jobs.

From the help:

> **about_Jobs**
>
> > When you start a background job, the command prompt returns
> >     immediately,
> >         even if the job takes an extended time to complete. You can continue to
> >         work in the session without interruption while the job runs.

So you can use

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { cmdlet1 }
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { cmdlet2 }
```

However, you need to have PowerShell configured for remoting, even when running a job locally.

I also stumbled over this:

- [Split-Job](http://www.jansveld.net/powershell/2008/12/split-job-093/)

Comment: Newest version of `Split-Job` appears to be here: https://github.com/ajansveld/split-job/blob/master/Split-Job.ps1

Answer (score 1):

If you need to stay on PowerShell v1, see if you can use the [PSEventing snap-in](http://pseventing.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cmd.exe /c call powershell cmdlet1
cmd.exe /c call powershell cmdlet2
```

Comment: Those will still be executed in the current console window one after another. `cmd /c start powershell cmdlet1` works, though.